# Standard Menu Item Location on Linux

Tags: linux, menu, x11

Where should I put a .desktop file in order to ensure that most desktop environments find it? Is there such a location? In addition, is there any standard place to put it in the user's home directory so that only that user sees it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gnome puts them in `/usr/share/applications`.  My personal ones seem to show up on `~/Desktop`, but these all seem Wine-related.  Some also show up in `~/.local/share/applications`. The good people at [freedesktop.org](http://freedesktop.org) have a specification of what they should look like, but I can't find a standard about where they should go.

Answer (score -1):

Unless I'm missing something, you're looking for the user's home directory, usually /home/user/.desktop

If you want to restrict it to just the user, issue `chmod 600 /home/username/.desktop` to ensure only the user can see it.

Comment: You are mistaken; I mean the .desktop file format, not ~/.desktop